# What's wrong with my OpenSSH Include directive?

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

Recently OpenSSH on macOS Sierra was upgraded to 7.3p1 [which means that the `Include` config directive is available](https://superuser.com/questions/247564/is-there-a-way-for-one-ssh-config-file-to-include-another-one), hurray!

However I'm having problems actually using it.

I have the following `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
Hostname github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/github_rsa

Host den
HostName narzt-desktop.local
User camden
GSSAPIAuthentication no
AddressFamily inet

Host walle
User CamdenNarzt
HostName WALLE.local
AddressFamily inet
GSSAPIAuthentication no

Include ~/.ssh/config.d/*
```

I saw [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1408558) that there might be some useful debug output if I added a bunch of `-v` flags to my ssh commands, yet when I test the config for a host in one of the included files I get this:

```
$ \ssh -vvvvG git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config
debug3: /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config line 31: Including file /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/family.conf depth 0 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/family.conf
debug3: /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config line 31: Including file /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/icloud.conf depth 0 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/icloud.conf
debug3: /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config line 31: Including file /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/metabolistics.conf depth 0 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/metabolistics.conf
debug3: /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config line 31: Including file /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/scanimetrics.conf depth 0 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d/scanimetrics.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
user camdennarzt
hostname git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
port 22
addressfamily any
batchmode no
canonicalizefallbacklocal yes
canonicalizehostname false
challengeresponseauthentication yes
checkhostip yes
compression no
controlmaster false
enablesshkeysign no
clearallforwardings no
exitonforwardfailure no
fingerprinthash SHA256
forwardagent no
forwardx11 no
forwardx11trusted no
gatewayports no
gssapiauthentication no
gssapidelegatecredentials no
hashknownhosts no
hostbasedauthentication no
identitiesonly no
kbdinteractiveauthentication yes
nohostauthenticationforlocalhost no
passwordauthentication yes
permitlocalcommand no
protocol 2
proxyusefdpass no
pubkeyauthentication yes
requesttty auto
rhostsrsaauthentication no
rsaauthentication yes
streamlocalbindunlink no
stricthostkeychecking ask
tcpkeepalive yes
tunnel false
useprivilegedport no
verifyhostkeydns false
visualhostkey no
updatehostkeys false
canonicalizemaxdots 1
compressionlevel 6
connectionattempts 1
forwardx11timeout 1200
numberofpasswordprompts 3
serveralivecountmax 3
serveraliveinterval 0
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostbasedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
loglevel DEBUG3
macs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
xauthlocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
canonicaldomains
globalknownhostsfile /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
userknownhostsfile ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts2
sendenv LANG
sendenv LC_*
connecttimeout none
tunneldevice any:any
controlpersist no
escapechar ~
ipqos lowdelay throughput
rekeylimit 0 0
streamlocalbindmask 0177
```

(Ignore the line numbers in the first bit, I deleted some comments to save space in the question) The user should be the user specified in the `~/.ssh/config.d/metabolistics.conf` file, and the identity file should likewise be the one specified in the included config file. I can't post the contents of the `~/.ssh/config.d/metabolistics.conf` file, but it's format is exactly the same as the main `~/.ssh/config` file but without any further includes.

I checked the permissions and they look fine to me:

```
$ ls -lhRa ~/.ssh/config* 
-rw-------  1 camdennarzt  staff   541B  1 Jan 14:22 /Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config

/Users/camdennarzt/.ssh/config.d:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  6 camdennarzt  staff   204B  1 Jan 14:37 .
drwx------  9 camdennarzt  staff   306B  1 Jan 14:22 ..
-rw-------  1 camdennarzt  staff   260B  1 Jan 14:16 family.conf
-rw-------  1 camdennarzt  staff   303B  1 Jan 14:17 icloud.conf
-rw-------  1 camdennarzt  staff   524B  1 Jan 14:15 metabolistics.conf
-rw-------  1 camdennarzt  staff   1.6K  1 Jan 14:15 scanimetrics.conf
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The clue was in the `ssh_config` man page:

> Include
>
> Include the specified configuration file(s).  Multiple pathnames may be specified and each pathname may contain glob(3) wildcards and, for user configurations, shell-like ``~'' references to user home directories.
>
> Files without absolute paths are assumed to be in ~/.ssh if included
> in a user configuration file or /etc/ssh if included from the system
> configuration file.  Include directive may appear inside a Match or
> Host block to perform conditional inclusion.

I had my `Include` statement trailing a `Host` directive so it was being included into that Host's config.

Comment: In other words the `Include` directive must go to the top of the `config` file (before the "body" made of `Host` blocks)

Comment: Thanks, while that does follow from the docs it isn't immediately obvious when trying to figure out why a config isn't working :)

Comment: @larsks Agree, wasted so many hours debugging because of this rule.

Comment: How does _"Include directive may appear inside a Match or Host block to perform conditional inclusion."_ imply _"Include must go at the top of the file in order to wortk"_?

Comment: Indenting the `Host`/`Match` blocks with a TAB _really_ helps debugging, and also remembering that _the only global statements are the start of a file, everything after the first block belongs to a block_ (that's why you need `Match all` or `Host *` for trailing statements)

Answer (score 17):

You can leave the `Include` statement at the end of the file if you precede it with `Match all`. This terminates the previous Host/Match, and then conditionally always includes the file(s). So, the file would end with:

```
Match all
Include config.d/*
```

Comment: As an aside, only lines starting with `#` or empty lines count as comments; you can't put a comment on the same line as `Match` or `Host`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Actually no.

It's a short-circuit bug in the `SSHCONF_NEVERMATCH` flag's use.

I'm working on diffs to fix the mess. Includes should be able to go anywhere (and also be recursive) be it main body or inside a Host|Match block.

The only tricky bit is knowing when you've unrolled the stack of `read_config_file_depth()` and can resume processing Host|Match again.

I'll be posting to [my branch](https://github.com/tb3088/openssh-portable/tree/fix_include-processing) when I have something.

Answer (score -1):

The main configuration file is probably:

```
CheckHostIP yes
Host *
[Indent] [Here are some global configurations required by all hosts]
[line break]
Host github.com
[Indent][Some configurations]
[line break]
Include other configuration files
```

The contents of other configuration files are:

```
Host specific host name
[indent] Configuration of this host
```

At this time, other configuration files cannot take effect.
If you change the main configuration file to:

```
CheckHostIP yes
Host *
[Indent] [Here are some global configurations required by all hosts]
[line break]
Include other configuration files
[line break]
Host github.com
[Indent][Some configurations]
```

Or:

```
CheckHostIP yes
Include other configuration files
Host *
[Indent] [Here are some global configurations required by all hosts]
[line break]
Host github.com
[Indent][Some configurations]
[line break]
```

or:

```
CheckHostIP yes
Host *
[Indent] [Here are some global configurations required by all hosts]
[line break]
Host github.com
[Indent][Some configurations]
[line break]
Match all
Include other configuration files
```

Then the global configuration and other configuration files can take effect.

And as @mestrelion said,
I had added indent already, but it is no effect, useless for debugging...Hummmmmm...